# Axios giving 401 (Unauthorized). I am trying to get userdata through react frontend passed to DRF Social Oauth2. Same is working on POSTMAN

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, axios

Below are the two files LoginScreen.JS which has a submit handler that submits the input. Here we import the axios instance from login.JS. I have also attached the same working example from PostMan.

Below are the two files LoginScreen.JS which has a submit handler that submits the input. Here we import the axios instance from login.JS. I have also attached the same working example from PostMan.

**login.js**

```
const baseURL='http://127.0.0.1:8000/';

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: baseURL,
    timeout: 5000,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        accept: 'application/json'
    },
    
});

export default axiosInstance
```

**LoginScreen.js**

```
const submitHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        
        axiosInstance
            .post(`auth/token/`,{
             username: email,
             password: password,
             grant_type: 'password',
             client_id: 'Vqvt1yp2HahF8KgwOS3BrWaCUX8ViDGCrn3VfJkz',
             client_secret: '1XiPeWz1HU4fRdS8lHIKhQZykbyMl8FGByCUa4s8gye68EauxZSlWvKSnCuD990wERmMF8RASsLeHxQGLeNFm8EhaHzzD9bi1aMRY93cXptstyBFQKnH73KFYLalDXWh'
            })
            .then((res) => {
                localStorage.setItem('access_token', res.data.access);
                localStorage.setItem('refresh_token', res.data.refresh);
            });
    };
```

[image: Error on Console]
[image: Postman Working]

Answer (score 0):

Your client secret key is same as client id in axios instance. Please change it to client secret.

Comment: I have changed it, but the 401 error persists. I have tried hardcoding all the entries too, it is still the same 401 error.

Comment: Maybe your client id and client secret are expired. Or the user might not be registered. Can you check whether you are sending the correct email and password or not?

Comment: Okay, I created a new super user and hardcoded the inputs, and the object is being returned correctly. I am wondering if the 401 error occurs after expiration.

Comment: Instead of hard-coding, send the dynamic values. That could be the problem because the client id and secret ids do not get expired that fast.